# segmentation fault when trying to load SDL image in another thread with IMG_LoadTexture

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, sdl, sdl-2

I try to make my SDL program (a little game written in plain C, no C++) more efficient and now have two SDL_Threads. The main thread does only the rendering stuff and pumps the events because I want to filter "quit" signals to terminate the program at any time.

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    initGameAndSecondThread();
    SDL_SetEventFilter(myFilterFunction, NULL);
    
    while(Game.running) {
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Game.renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(Game.renderer);
        renderFunction();
        SDL_RenderPresent(Game.renderer);
    }
}
```

and the other thread does the magic. So thread number two looks basically like this:

```c
int secondThread(void* data){
    SDL_Event event;
    while(true) {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            eventHandlerFunction(&event);
        }
    }
}
```

If the user now for example clicks on a button and some image loads in the background I get a segmentation fault. Because of my genious debugging skills I found out that this happens when the main thread tries to render: `SDL_RenderPresent(Game.renderer);` and the second thread tries to load an image like this:

```c
SDL_Texture* img = IMG_LoadTexture(Game.renderer, path);
```

My question is now: Is there any possibility that my second thread loads an image at the same time my first thread renders? Or do I have to use locks or something like that?

I expected those two operations to run parallel with no SIGSEV because this does not make any sense to me. My coworker on this project had the idea to lock a mutex before loading an image which kind of minimized the probability for the problem to occur for him I think, but does not make any sense for me because there is no other thread than the second thread that ever uses `IMG_LoadTexture`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `SDL_PollEvent` in a secondary thread. Use `SDL_PeepEvents` if you want to do that kind of thing.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender "This API is not designed to be used from multiple threads". The only correct answer is "don't call anything that uses renderer on secondary threads". You can load and decode image (i.e. `IMG_Load`), but you have to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` on graphics thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I must have missed that information. Because there are SDL_Threads I thought that SDL supported rendering on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nelfeal and @keltar I now know that in my use case I can't use multiple threads. Rendering and event handling are both in some way limited to run on the main thread. `SDL_PollEvent` and like every function you have to pass the renderer must be called on the graphics thread.

Comment: From what I understand, it's not that SDL isn't designed for multithreading, it's that some platforms just don't support multithreaded rendering. SDL can't do much about it. However, you can absolutely use multithreading as long as you call the rendering functions in the main thread. You can make other threads send messages for drawing things, but you need to implement that yourself.

Comment: Even not considering technical limitations - it is logically problemmatic because order of drawing is often important. Even APIs like vulkan which are specifically designed for multithreading allows each thread to record their own separate command buffer, but submission of those buffers have to happen in single thread.

Comment: And if we're talking about SDL - this statement is only about renderer. Many other things could be used. E.g. event queue is explicitly thread-safe, as long as you can ensure it doesn't fall to `PumpEvents` (mostly OS limitation; you can get away with it on some OSes but not others). As I've said before, you could IMG_Load your images on second thread, decompressing your png/jpeg/whatever, but then upload result to GPU on graphics thread. You can use SDL's event queue with custom event to send commands, or implement your own way.

Comment: So on the one hand you are telling me that I should only call `SDL_PollEvent` from the main thread, on the other hand you say that the event queue is explicitly thread safe. Now what? I had the `SDL_PollEvent` on another thread and that seemed to be the origin of my problem.

Comment: @MrKleeblatt That's what I said in my first comment: use `SDL_PeepEvents` if you want to do that. [`SDL_PumpEvents`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) is the only thing that needs to be called on the main thread, but `SDL_PollEvent` and `SDL_WaitEvent` both implicitly call `SDL_PumpEvents`, so you can't use those either. It's all in the wiki.